# What uses up more space in FLASH? static variable or global variable

Tags: c, stm32, ansi-c

As the title says, what uses up more space in FLASH (in an STM32 µC for example)? Declaring a global variable or declaring a static variable inside a function? Or do they take equal space? Both variables are available throughout the whole runtime of the program in my understanding. Just their scopes are different.

Comment: Those kind of variables behaves same way. Difference in flash occupation is with uninitialized (auto-initialized to `0`) and initialized variable. In second case values are usually stored in `data section` on flash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have 0-initialized global and static variables. Those normally take up no flash, because they are placed in memory location which is allocated and zeroed when program starts and does not come from flash.

You can initialize the variables with value too. In that case they are placed in the initalized data segment, so take up space from flash according to size of the data type.

Static variables inside functions you can also initialize with code. That initializaton must happen at runtime, but can happen only once, so it actually generates more code, which will in almost any case take more space than the size of the data (not necessarily, at least if you initialize a large enough struct with a function return value). You can do almost same for non-const global variables too, you just need to leave them 0-initialized orignally and put assignment (for example) at the start of `main()`, where it takes the same space as initialization of function scope static variable by code takes elsewhere.

Conclusion, both global and function-scope static variables take up same amount of space.

---

Above assumes "global variable" in embedded context, or as a file-scope static variable. If it is exported global symbol in a dynamically linkable executable, then relocation information for that symbol will take some space in the executable binary. However, I don't think given example system supports or uses relocatable executables.

Answer (score 2):

The formal term for "available throughout the whole runtime" is *static storage duration*. Variables declared at file scope ("global") as well as all variables declared with `static` both have static storage duration.

So there is a relation between scope and storage duration: scope can dictate what storage duration a variable gets. But there is no relation between scope and memory usage.

How much space a variable takes up only depends on how large that variable type is. Scope and storage duration has nothing to do with it.

On most compilers/linkers, there are usually two things required for a variable to end up in flash:

- It must be declared as `const`, and
- It must have static storage duration

If these conditions aren't met, the variable will not end up in flash/nvm, regardless of which scope it is declared at.

Comment: What do you mean by "the variable will not end up in flash/nvm" if it is not `const`? I mean, the initial value comes from somewhere, so if it isn't in flash directly as data (loaded to RAM), then it must stored in flash there as code. But why, if value is known at compile time, because code will both take more space and increase startup time? (Note, I'm not an expert in embedded stuff, this is a serious question.)

Comment: @hyde If it isn't const, then it is a read/write variable. Read/write variables can obviously not be allocated in flash. If such a variable has an initializer, then indeed the initializer is stored in flash, and written to the variable during initialization.

Comment: So, what you are saying is, const variable may not take up any "normal"/volatile RAM, when flash memory is mapped to to CPU address space and accessed directly. But I would interpret question's "uses up more space" as including any initialization data or code, which is added by defining the variable in source code.

Comment: @hyde The question just seems to be general confusion about how variables are stored in memory. [Recommended reading](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/237759/6102).

Answer (score 2):

> As the title says, what uses up more space in FLASH (in an STM32 µC for example)? Declaring a global variable or declaring a static variable inside a function? Or do they take equal space?

Using arm-none-eabi-gcc as the reference for an STM32 build, neither take any flash space at all.

Global and static variables that are not declared `const` go either into the `.data` section if they require startup initialisation or into `.bss` if they don't. Both of those segments are placed into SRAM by your linker script. If you're doing C++ then static C++ classes end up in `.bss`.

If you do declare them `const` then they'll  be placed into the `.rodata` section which, if you consult your linker script you should find being located into a subsection of `.text` which is in flash. Flash is usually more plentiful than SRAM so do make use of `const` where you can.

Finally, the optimizer can come along and totally rearrange anything it sees fit, including the elimination of storage in favour of inlining.